# Add internal links to a MARP presentation

Tags: markdown, marp

I have a basic MARP presentation, https://github.com/marp-team/marp. I would like to add links to emulate footnotes or references. Is this possible, what about the PDF export?

```
Some text with source. [1]
```

The "1" should link to another slide:

```
1. some description
```

PS
I do not have enough reputation to create the `marp` tag for this question, as described by the MARP Readme.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a couple of different options depending on what you want them to look like.

Look at the Slide 3 example below. Just create a normal markdown link and put `#n` after the filename where `n` = your desired slide number.

For links that look like footnotes you can apply the styling found in Slide 2.

```
---
marp: true
theme: gaia
paginate: true
class: invert
---

# Slide 1

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur non maximus tortor, eget rutrum turpis. Suspendisse tortor ex, dictum a turpis a, imperdiet imperdiet nisi.

---

<!-- _footer: "1. www.google.com" -->

# Slide 2

- Footnote link only <sup>1<sup>.
- Footnote and superscript link <sup>[1][1]</sup>.

[1]: https://www.google.com
---

# Slide 3

Inline link [to slide 1](./file-name.html#1)
```

Comment: Thank you, I hoped that there would be less manual management, for example to have MARP create a list of all foot-notes for you. But I should be able to do this externally.